# Vue: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropbox

[image]

I'm trying to load images from dropbox into a vue carousel. It looks similar to

```
    export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          src: "/52lv.PNG"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/sky.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/bird.jpg"
        },
        {
          src: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/planet.jpg"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

except with dropbox images

None of the images loaded, although pasting the address into a browser works. looking at the console I see:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/html.
```

Because these are images ,it looks like the wrong mime type. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It's annoying as hell. Watching this question because I can't seem to fix this new CORB issue either

Comment: The 'www.dropbox.com/s/...' links aren't links to the image files themselves, but rather Dropbox web pages showing the shared content. You can try using the `raw=1` parameter documented here: https://help.dropbox.com/desktop-web/force-download That would make the links redirect to the actual file content. (This would require the client to follow the redirects though; I don't know if your client will do so.)